# Split the data in to 4 different categories

Tags: javascript

For example - I have the following data
This below values are in an array it is not key and value.

```
tier2_rightend: 10766
tier1_rightend: 10766
tier1_leftend: 2719
tier1_leftstart: 1
tier2_maxjunctions: 2
tier2_leftend: 2719
tier2_leftstart: 1
tier2_minjunctions: 1
tier2_rightstart: 10275
tier1_minjunctions: 2
tier1_maxjunctions: 2
tier1_rightstart: 10275
```

I need the result in following format

```
tier1 = tier1_leftstart(value)  -  tier1_leftend(value) ,tier1_rightstart(value) -tier1_rightend(value)
```

So I need to have 4 arrays as tier1 left start tier1 left end
Tier1 right start and tier1 right end

Also I need similar thing to be done for tier 2

Can can body help?

Comment: please add the data you have with the data structure and the wanted result with the data structure.

Comment: Var a = [tier2_rightend: 10766,tier1_rightend: 10766,
tier1_leftend: 2719,
tier1_leftstart: 1,
tier2_maxjunctions: 2,
tier2_leftend: 2719,
tier2_leftstart: 1,
tier2_minjunctions: 1,
tier2_rightstart: 10275,
tier1_minjunctions: 2,
tier1_maxjunctions: 2,
tier1_rightstart: 10275]

I need the result in following format 

 tier1_leftstart(value)  -  tier1_leftend(value) ,tier1_rightstart(value) -tier1_rightend(value)

Tier1 = 1-2719,10275-10766
(Like this)
 I need similar thing to be done for tier 2

Answer (score 0):

You could take two nested arrays for the key parts and create a new object with the result.

```js
var object = { tier2_rightend: 10766, tier1_rightend: 10766, tier1_leftend: 2719, tier1_leftstart: 1, tier2_maxjunctions: 2, tier2_leftend: 2719, tier2_leftstart: 1, tier2_minjunctions: 1, tier2_rightstart: 10275, tier1_minjunctions: 2, tier1_maxjunctions: 2, tier1_rightstart: 10275 },
    result = {};

['tier1', 'tier2'].forEach(k => ['left', 'right'].forEach(l => {
    var key = [k, l].join('_');
    result[key] = object[key + 'start'] - object[key + 'end'];
}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: What if I want the result as {tier1_leftstart: 1}

Comment: All as the separate result

Comment: what is the calculation of `{ tier1_leftstart: 1 }`?

Comment: So that picking up of each value is easier if I want pickup the value of each in text box , so I can have them differently placed as tier1_left start in one textbox , if I want to pick up end , i can store tier1_left end in a separate object.

Comment: if(k=="tier1" && l == 'left')
    {
       tier1_left_start[key + 'start'] = object[key + 'start'];
       tier1_left_end[key + 'end']     = object[key + 'end'];
    }
    if(k=="tier1" && l == 'right')
    {
       tier1_right_start[key + 'start'] = object[key + 'start'];
       tier1_right_end[key + 'end']     = object[key + 'end'];
    }
    if(k=="tier2" && l == 'left')
    {
       tier2_left_start[key + 'start'] = object[key + 'start'];
       tier2_left_end[key + 'end']     = object[key + 'end'];
    } 
 Adding Something like this  in the foreach

Comment: i have no idea, what you need.